# Why is message.awaitReactions always rejecting?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a command where if a user reacts to a message then the bot would send a message after a certain amount of time.

This is my code. it is supposed to send the 'you have reacted to the command' when I react with the emoji, but for some reason it always sends 'its been 10 seconds and no one has reacted'. Does anyone know what I did wrong in the code?

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
        && user.id === message.author.id;
}
        
message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
             message.reply('you have reacted to this command');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.channel.send('its been 10 seconds and no one has reacted');
    })
```

Comment: Can you try logging the error to see if it’s the timeout, or an error in the `.then` callback?

Comment: If anything within the `.then` handler throws, your code blindly assumes it's because of the timeout. Consider instead using the form `.then(successCallback, failureCallback)` so that "it's been 10 seconds" is only sent if it's specifically the `awaitReactions` call that rejects.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work just fine.